# PySpark LinearRegressionWithSGD, model predict dimensions mismatch

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I've come across the following error:

> AssertionError: dimension mismatch

I've trained a linear regression model using PySpark's LinearRegressionWithSGD. 
However when I try to make a prediction on the training set, I get "dimension mismatch" error.

Worth mentioning:

1. Data was scaled using StandardScaler, but the predicted value was not.
2. As can be seen in code the features used for training were generated by PCA.

Some code:

```
pca_transformed = pca_model.transform(data_std)
X = pca_transformed.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
data = train_votes.zip(pca_transformed)
labeled_data = data.map(lambda x : LabeledPoint(x[0], x[1:]))
linear_regression_model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(labeled_data, iterations=10)
```

The prediction is the source of the error, and these are the variations I tried:

```
pred = linear_regression_model.predict(pca_transformed.collect())
pred = linear_regression_model.predict([pca_transformed.collect()])    
pred = linear_regression_model.predict(X.collect())
pred = linear_regression_model.predict([X.collect()])
```

The regression weights:

```
DenseVector([1.8509, 81435.7615])
```

The vectors used:

```
pca_transformed.take(1)
[DenseVector([-0.1745, -1.8936])]

X.take(1)
[(-0.17449817243564397, -1.8935926689554488)]

labeled_data.take(1)
[LabeledPoint(22221.0, [-0.174498172436,-1.89359266896])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
pred = linear_regression_model.predict(pca_transformed)
```

pca_transformed is of type RDD.

The [function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py) handles RDD's and arrays differently:

```
def predict(self, x):
    """
    Predict the value of the dependent variable given a vector or
    an RDD of vectors containing values for the independent variables.
    """
    if isinstance(x, RDD):
        return x.map(self.predict)
    x = _convert_to_vector(x)
    return self.weights.dot(x) + self.intercept
```

When a simple array is used, there might be a dimension mismatch issue (like the error in the question above).

As can be seen, if x is not an RDD, it's being converted to a vector. The thing is the dot product will not work unless you take x[0].

Here is the error reproduced:

```
j = _convert_to_vector(pca_transformed.take(1))
linear_regression_model.weights.dot(j) + linear_regression_model.intercept
```

This works just fine:

```
j = _convert_to_vector(pca_transformed.take(1))
linear_regression_model.weights.dot(j[0]) + linear_regression_model.intercept
```